# How to prevent a route from being accessed via its associated module/controller/action path in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, seo, http-status-code-404

Let's say I create a route:

```
$account_route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
    'account',
    array(
        'module'     => 'user',
        'controller' => 'account',
        'action'     => 'edit',
    )
);
```

Now this page can be visited via `example.com/account`, AND `example.com/user/account/edit`.

I'd like to create one point of entry for all my pages for SEO purposes and to prevent users from trying to figure out how my app is architected on the server.  Is there a way to return a 404 to anyone who tries to access a URL through the module/controller/action pattern for where a designated route exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the default route or remove it:

```
$router->removeDefaultRoutes();
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising.  But then I'd have to define a custom route for every URL because I'd get `Route default is not defined` errors.  With some URLs I'd like to use the default.  If worse comes to worse I think I could use this by overriding everything.

Comment: You could define default route for everything else.

Comment: I think this is the way to go, but you can then re-add the default `:module/:controller/:action/*` route with some restrictions, e.g. a whitelist of specific modules that you don't have other routes on.